# Rename field in embedded document with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection in mongodb and I want to rename some fields name. My collection is like:

```
    {
    "_id": "",
    "user": "5a02d87ac12d314721bd9a15",
    "item": {
        "5b20db50a32c0e02693ffad6": {
            "item_value": [{
                "timepstamp": "",
                "value": 0.2
            }, {
                "timepstamp": "",
                "value": 0.8
            }, {
                "timepstamp": "",
                "value": 0.9
            }]
        },
        "843ujsafu88gfs88987898f": {
            "item_value": [{
                "timepstamp": "",
                "value": 0.2
            }, {
                "timepstamp": "",
                "value": 0.8
            }, {
                "timepstamp": "",
                "value": 0.9
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to rename the `"5b20db50a32c0e02693ffad6"` and `"843ujsafu88gfs88987898f"` which are the keys after the item with new values i have lets say `"12345x"`and `"12345y"`

How can I perform that query in pymongo? I can retrieve the value from the collection with the following code:

```
db = client['db']
collection = db['col']
res = collection.find({})

for item in res:
    items= item["item"]
    for key in items:
         print (key)
    ## collection.update({}, {$rename: {item["item"][key]: item["item"][new_item_id]}}, False, True)
```

That code return the keys that I want to rename. How can I do so?

**EDIT:** I tried to use the collection update and the method rename. It seems that it does not work. How can I change that field only and how I will use properly pymongo here?

**EDIT2:**
     In my case I need to do something like that:

```
 _id = res['_id']
 item.pop('_id')   # this is imp
 _user = item['user']
 item.pop('user')   # this is imp

 collection.update({'_id': _id, 'user': _user }, {$set: item})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To rename field in MongoDB, we usually use the [`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) update operate which works beautifully with [embedded document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#rename-a-field-in-an-embedded-document) as well.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


uri = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"

old_fields_names = ["5b20db50a32c0e02693ffad6",
                    "843ujsafu88gfs88987898f"]
new_fields_names = ["12345x", "12345y"]
with MongoClient(uri) as client:
    db = client.db
    col = db.col
    update_doc = {f"item.{old}": f"item.{new}"
                  for old, new in zip(old_fields_names, new_field_names)}
    update = {"$rename": update_doc}
    col.update_many({}, update)
```

Note the use of the context manager aka *with statement* to open the connection to the database, which ensure the connection is close when we are done with the operation to avoid leaking resources.

Comment: What if I do not have the update_doc and I want to replace the value in the for loop with the new one?

Comment: I mean I understand the solution, but in my case what will be the query: something like: collection.update({}, {$rename: {item["item"][key]: item["item"][new_item_id]}}, False, True)?

Comment: That doc["Sla"][key] returns the sub-json value while I want to rename the key name.

Comment: `update_doc` is a variable I created based on the values you provided. You really don't need to load the data into memory just to rename the fields in this particular case. Forget about the for loop you have in the accepted answer. There are many things wrong with that answer

Comment: The issue is that i need to check one by one the variables in my dataset, thus the key value and then rename it with my mapping value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already come to right steps only few more steps remaining. Below will work. Also, I am assuming that you already have a mapping which key you want to replace and to what  -

```
db = client['db']
collection = db['col']
res = collection.find({})

for doc in res:
    items= doc["item"]
    for key in items:
         # Now suppose you want to replace this key 
        if key want to replace:
             temp = copy.deepcopy(items[key])
             items["new_Key_name"] = temp
             items.pop(key)  # deleting old key with data

     # Now one document has been modified with expected key Now update the DB
     _id = copy.deepcopy(doc['_id'])
     doc.pop('_id')   # this is imp
     collection.update({'_id': _id }, {$set: doc})
```

Now One Suggestion in the End. Do not use above approach because there are DB Queries inside Loop which is not good. Learn about BulkWrite given in Pymongo Documentation. Its very easy.

Comment: Your pymonogColl is it the collection, right? Yes the mapping is the same variable new_item_id.

Comment: Yes Changed the name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also not sure the doc to what it correspond?

Comment: doc is just the iterator.  It's more intuitive in Mongo terminology.  as you did above res = collection.find({}).  It means all documents are stored in res as a cursor.  So I just named it doc which you have item. Item as iterator name is very ambigous

Comment: True true item gets really messy as a term. Btw in the collection.update I have an error was the same that i had before with $rename expression expected found bad character in the dollar character and end of file expected in the last parenthesis.

Comment: I think now you should do some debugging by printing the doc just before update query.  May be some improper dictionary or data is there.  Print here some debug log i will help

Comment: I think I need "" characters in the query.

Comment: _id = res["_id"] this line does not work: pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query. The pop(key) removes correctly the whole field of the key. I can use item (doc) but not res.

Comment: Oh I am very sorry.  it should be 
_id = doc["_id"]

Comment: One last question. I update my post, should I also include the field user?
_user = item['user']
 item.pop('user')   # this is imp

 collection.update({'_id': _id, 'user': _user }, {$set: item})

Comment: As I see your Edit2.  Looks like you want to update doc only for perticular users, So you dont need to doc.pop(''user).
Below one lines are wrong.  
item.pop('user')   
collection.update({'_id': _id, 'user': _user }, {$set: item})
you dont need them

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your problem.

Comment: So what I am replacing then with collection.update({'_id': _id}, {"$set": doc})?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180890/discussion-between-shailendra2014-and-jose-ramon).

Comment: The approach works, however, in the second iteration of the loop for the keys I am getting that error:

Comment: keyerror _id it seems that some id is wrongly changed because maybe of the pop.

Comment: I think you should change _id  = doc['_id'] to _id = copy.deepcopy(doc['_id']) in third last line in my code above